# Clickhouse exception 271 - CANNOT_DECOMPRESS while SELECT

Tags: clickhouse

I'm getting `271` Error when I try to select some columns from the table. Some columns are OK, but some leads to exception.

This is my query:

```
SELECT <collName> 
FROM default.<tableName> 
LIMIT 1
```

Exception:

> Exception on client:
> Code: 271. DB::Exception: Data compressed with different methods, given method byte 0x00, previous method byte 0x82: while receiving packet from :. (CANNOT_DECOMPRESS)

Have tried to change `max_threads` - nothing changed.

Comment: It's a bug in Clikhouse or data corruption. Use `check table` to check for corruption. Upgrade  Clikhouse.

Comment: @DennyCrane  The data maintains integrity.

Comment: It's a bug in Clikhouse. Upgrade Clikhouse.

Comment: @DennyCrane  I already have ClickHouse client  `version 23.3.1.1385`.  According this link https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/releases the latest version is `23.2.4.12`

Comment: then file a new issue https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/new/choose